# The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated While Sending email using SMTP client

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, smtp, dispatcher

I am getting following error:

> he SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not
>   authenticated

I have already set UseDefaultCredentials= false and enablessl= true
Still i am getting the same exception.

My credentials are correct as i can log in to outtlook using same credentials
I dnt know where i am goging wrong

Comment: I'm facing this same issue. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

looks like a permission issue

In the Exchange Management Console, under the Server Configuration node, select Hub Transport and the name of the server. In the Receive Connectors pane, open either of the Recive Connectors (my default installation created 2) or you can create a new one just for TFS (I also tried this and it worked). For any of these connectors, open Properties and on the Permission Groups tab ensure that Anonymous Users is selected (it's not by default).